# Logging, Cadastro, Permissões C#

Tags: c#, ddd

Galera eu gostaria de saber de uma forma lógica e robusta e bem clara,

de que forma se comporta a organização em um software que irá possuir:

-Logging(toda e qualquer ação executada no sistema deve ser registrada)
ex: "Usuário X inseriu um produto novo no sistema, na Data Y", "Usuário Z alterou o produto na data Y".

-Controle de acesso bem dinâmico, cada usuário cadastrado pode pertencer a um    "grupo" que possui permissões específicas do sistema. O administrador do sistema pode criar grupos de permissões assim como dar permissões específicas para cada tipo de usuário também.

Ex: adicionar pedido, remover pedido.

a minha dúvida não é como fazer ou implementar tudo isso.

minha dúvida é, caso eu esteja usando n-layer arquitecture, algo do tipo DDD ou outra coisa parecida, como ficariam organizadas de forma clara, as abstrações, interfaces, e classes concretas, em quais camadas, tudo bonitinho e legível seguindo ubiquitous language.

Comment: Aguardo, também, uma boa solução, pois vejo muitos sistemas orientados a IF por causa desse tipo de coisa.

Comment: exatamente, queria saber ao certo como os "grandes" implementam essas coisas, como por exemplo RestfulSoa  e por ai vai...